# requestAnimationFrame on react - doesn't stop state updates when tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**browser:** chrome 62

**react version:** 16

I have built a stopwatch component on react using `requestAnimationFrame` for experimentation purposes.

[Blog post of css-trick says](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/) that the beautify of `requestAnimationFrame` is that it stops when the tab is inactive.

however, my component state is still getting updated after I move tabs.

What am I missing? See the code:

```
import React from 'react';
class Clock extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            passedTime: 0,
            startTime: new Date()
        };
        this.repeatOften = this.repeatOften.bind(this)
        requestAnimationFrame(this.repeatOften);
    }
    repeatOften() {
        const currentTime = new Date().getTime()
        const passedTime = (currentTime - this.state.startTime) / 1000
        this.setState({
            passedTime
        })
        requestAnimationFrame(this.repeatOften)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.passedTime}!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Clock
```

Comment: I have version 61 and it works perfectly. Are you sure you have no polyfill that overwrites requestAnimationFrame with something like setTimeout?

Comment: what do u mean by works?  the stopwatch stops to count the seconds when u move tabs and continue when you return?

Comment: yes. i was just `console.log("...") ` outputting, watching the console. as soon as I changed the tab, the console stopped outputting.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWMeNZ

Comment: well i'm using react, maybe it has something to do with it. you are not testing on similiar enviroment. i am using the `create-react-app` boilerplate without any modification except this component i posted here.

Comment: well you could try to `requestAnimationFrame.toString()` to check if it returns something like `[native code]`. If it does, there is some other bug or maybe a setting in you particular case

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the behavior of `requestAnimationFrame` is universally defined when the tab is not focused, it varies from browser to browser so I wouldn't rely upon that too much. If you want precise control over what your app does when the tab is focused or not, then you should listen for the [window.onblur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur) and [window.onfocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus) events.

Comment: i am using chrome 62. added that information to the question. if you check `can i use` u will find it has full chrome support since version 23 of chrome.